# Can we use same service to communicate between multiple pair of components in Angular using same service

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-services

Let's say My page has 4 components Comp1, Comp2, Comp3, and Comp4 (All unrelated components). If I want to communicate between Comp1 and Comp2. Also between Comp3 and Comp4 same time. Is it possible to use the same service to communicate between them?

Comment: I want to answer yes. But can you describe more what you've done and what you want to do please ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is an injectable service at the root can serve as a means of communicating between components.  Using EmitEvent you can broadcast & subscribe to specific calls.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class myInjectableService {
    public message: EmitEvent<string> = new EmitEvent();

    public SendMessage(msg:string): void {
         this.message.emit(msg);
    } 
}



@Component({
    selector: "sendComponent",
    template: "<div (click)='SendMessage()'></div>"
})
export class SenderComponent {
    constructor(private injectable: myInjectableService) {}
    public SendMessage(): void {
        this.injectable.SendMessage('Test');
    }
} 



@Component({
    selector: "receiveComponent",
    template: "<div>{{Message}}</div>"
})
export class ReceiverComponent {
    constructor(private injectable: myInjectableService) {
        this.injectable.subscribe((msg) => {
            this.Message = msg;
        })
    }
    public Message: string = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

Just declare a service that's provided in the main module (if you haven't touched the default is `appModule`).

The Service will look something like that:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService { 
    private $data = new Subject<CommunicationData>();
    public dataReceivedEvent = this.$data.asObservable();

    public setDataToSend(data: CommunicationData): void {
        this.$data.next(data);
    }
}
```

CommunicationData is an interface:

```
export interface CommunicationData { 
    eventName: string;
    data: any;
}
```

Now simply inject as a DI this service in every component you like.

```
constructor(
  private dataService: DataService
) { }
```

To send data from those components, you can just do that:

```
private sendData(): void { 
  this.dataService.setDataToSend({
    eventName: 'YourCustomEvent',
    data: null //can be anything
  });
}
```

To catch the event, simply do (in the onInit lifeCycle of the component):

```
this.dataService.dataReceivedEvent
  .subscribe(result => {
    if(result.eventName === 'YourCustomEvent') { 
      //foo
    } else if (result.eventName === '...') { 
      // something else
    } //and so on
  });
```

In this way you will have just one services that hold the communications between all your components.

Comment: Thanks @jacopo. That is an interesting solution.

Comment: I'm currently using this solution into a project that has around 120 components and 3million lines of code and I'd say it works like a charm.